# How to make the same reference style as used in articles?

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, superscripts

I want to use references with the same style as in the chemical articles I read. When I use `\footcite` it gives the right style in the text, but it also leaves a footnote in the bottom of the text. I do not want the footnote, only the reference number. Any suggestions?

This is how it looks in my document.[image: This comes up when I use <code>\footcite</code>]

A MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,danish,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\bibliography{ref} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip=0.1in
\begin{document}
Literature states\citep{Step_1}, but other literature also states\footcite{Step_2}...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It then looks like this.

[image: :(]

Comment: Then you should use `\cite` instead, not `\footcite`.

Comment: When I do that, my citation number appears within brackets and that is not how I want it. I want the reference number on top of the word without brackets.

Comment: No problem. What citation packages do you use? Could you provide the community with [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current setup *completely*.

Comment: ...you could try adding `\def\@cite#1#2{\textsuperscript{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}` to your preamble... this changes the default `[.]` display of `\cite` into `\textsuperscript{.}`.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks! Any ideas to make a comma between two reference without using math mode?

Comment: Yes, use `\supercite{X, Y, Z, ...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\footcite`, use `\supercite`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

Betram~\cite{bertram}.

Betram\supercite{bertram}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```